# How can i remove a line only if it is followed by a line that starts with the same character?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, fasta, reformat

I need some help with sed or awks.

How can i remove a line only if it is followed by a line that starts with the same character (in this case >)?

Example I have this:

```
>1_SRR1422294
ATCGTCAGGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAT
>2_SRR1422294
CGTCAGACGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAG
>5_SRR1422298
>5_SRR1422294
CGTCAGACGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAG
>6_SRR1422294
>6_SRR1422250
TGTTCATGGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAGC
>9_SRR1422294
GCGACTAGGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAGC
```

I want to get this:

```
>1_SRR1422294
ATCGTCAGGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAT
>2_SRR1422294
CGTCAGACGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAG
>5_SRR1422294
CGTCAGACGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAG
>6_SRR1422250
TGTTCATGGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAGC
>9_SRR1422294
GCGACTAGGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAGC
```

Note that not all the lines have the same numbers but they all have the same format, which is why I want to use regular expressions. If you could explain how to read the code you produce that would be really great.

Thank you so much!

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Poz '^>.*\n[^>].*' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the whole file follows that pattern (some number of lines starting with `>`, of which you want only the last, followed by a single line that should always be printed), you could use something like this:

```
awk '/^>/ { latest=$0 } !/^>/ { if (latest) { print latest; latest="" } print }'
```

If the line starts with `>`, then it is remembered (stored in the variable `latest`) but not printed. If the line doesn't start with `>`, then it is printed, but only after first printing whatever was most recently stored in `latest`.

The conditional means each printed `>` line will appear only once, even if there are multiple non-`>` lines in a row. Since that doesn't happen in your sample data, you may not need the complication, and could use this simpler unconditional version:

```
awk '/^>/ { latest=$0 } !/^>/ { print latest; print }'
```

Answer (score 2):

The needed result can be easily achieved by just using `uniq` command with `-w`(`--check-chars=N`) option:

```
cat testfile | uniq -w 3
```

The output:

```
>1_SRR1422294
ATCGTCAGGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAT
>2_SRR1422294
CGTCAGACGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAG
>5_SRR1422298
CGTCAGACGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCAACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAG
>6_SRR1422294
TGTTCATGGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAGC
>9_SRR1422294
GCGACTAGGTAGGGTTGCGCTCGTTGCGGGACTTAACCCACATCTCACGACACGAGCTGACGACAGCCATGCAGC
```

---

> ***-w, --check-chars***=*N*
>             compare no more than *N* characters in lines

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html

---

It will compare the first *N* characters of each line to make decision for repeated lines

Answer (score 2):

try: if your data is same as given sample Input_file then following may help you in same.

```
awk '/^>/{A=$0;next} {print A ORS $0;A=""}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/^>.*\n>/!P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and do not print the first of these lines if the first and second lines begin with `>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'N;/^>.*\n\w/!D' file #(GNU sed)
```

N: read next line into the pattern space.  
/^>.*\n\w/!D: delete the first line if the first line starts with ">" and the second line doesn't begin with a letter